# how to increment object property name in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

in my list of objects i have few similar properties.

week1
week2
week3
week4
week5
...

I would like to be able to display them in a table based on the selected number of weeks by the user.

My idea was to use the loop like below, but i can't add "i" to the @data.week#number

```
  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.numberOfWeeks; i++)
                        {
                      <td>@data.week@i.name</td>
                        }
```

Is there a way i can use the incrementation of "i" to add it to the object name ?

Comment: NO, property names are static and not dynamic likewise you are expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use variables to construct variable names. The names must remain static. If you really need that there is reflection, but that is not the best option.

Use a dictionary or list instead, so that `@data.weeks[@i].name` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have properties as values? Anyhow, if you really need to iterate properties and output their values you can try to use reflection:

```
 <td>@(data.GetType().GetProperty("week" + i).GetValue(data, null))</td>
```

But this is a bad practice. I would strongly recommend to change your data object and a view model.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to use Reflection inside your views.

Comment: Patrick, this is possible, since Adrian wanted to know how to print properties. Another question is that this is a bad practice and should not be used in views. We just don't know why he needs this and why his data model has properties as values.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions, i decided to use dictionary as suggested by Patrick, which solved the issue for me.